# How can I prevent a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have two elements:

```
<div class="a" onclick="a();">a
    <div class="b" onclick="b();">b</div>
</div>
```

When I click a just alert a is coming, but when I click b I just want to see alert b.

I think this example explain me better.

http://jsbin.com/Aruciyi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

As on example how can I get just alert b by clicking red block...

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.stopPropagation`, like this:

```
function b(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('b');
}
```

This traps the click event in the inner div and keeps it from bubbling up to the outer div.

ALSO: change your onclick attribute like this:

```
<div class="b" onclick="b(event);">b</div>
```

So you are explicitly passing the `event` object to the `b` function.

Comment: This does not work. I need to get alert b by clicking b (red) block.

Comment: @user2081672 Try now, I made a change.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers work, but I prefer to create one universal click function. I changed your classes to IDs so that getting them would be easier. Here's the code:

```
<div id="a" onclick="clickEvent(event, this);">a
  <div id="b" onclick="clickEvent(event, this);">b</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function clickEvent(e, o) {
  alert(o.id);
  event = e || window.event;
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/Pe7kb/)

Comment: the fuction did not work on IE I edited it as 
JavaScript: function b(){
  
  try{ window.event.cancelBubble = true;}
  catch(err){}
   try{  event = event || window.event || e;
       event.stopPropagation();}
  catch(err){}
   
  alert('b');
} but now it not working on firefox